# How can I use [formControlName] in dynamic component with the validation in Ionic 7/ Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

This is my typescript code for a field component with validation.

**RequiredText.ts**

```
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-required-text-field',
  templateUrl: './required-text-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./required-text-field.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgIf],
})
export class RequiredTextFieldComponent {

  @Input() generalForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() labelText: string;
  @Input() formValue: any;
  @Input() isSubmitted: boolean;

}
```

And this is the HTML

**RequiredText.html**

```
<ion-row class="animate__animated animate__zoomIn">
  <ion-col size="3">
    <b>{{labelText}}</b>
    <br>
    <span class="recom" *ngIf="!(isSubmitted && generalForm.controls.formValue.errors?.required)">
      Recommened
    </span>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="9" [formGroup]="generalForm">
    <ion-input [class.error-border]="isSubmitted && generalForm.controls.formValue.errors?.required" type="text"
      [formControlName]="formValue" [clearInput]="true"></ion-input>
    <span class="error ion-padding animate__animated animate__fadeIn"
      *ngIf="isSubmitted && generalForm.controls.formValue.errors?.required">
      Required.
    </span>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I want to use this component in my **home.html** I call the component like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="blogPostForm">
        <ion-grid>
          <app-required-text-field [generalForm]="blogPostForm" [labelText]="blogPostTitle"
            [formValue]="blogPostForm.get('title')" [isSubmitted]="isSubmitted"></app-required-text-field>        
        </ion-grid>
</form>
```

And this is my **home.ts** file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Keyboard } from '@capacitor/keyboard';
import { RequiredTextFieldComponent } from "../../components/required-text-field/required-text-field.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
  standalone: true, 
  imports: [IonicModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RequiredTextFieldComponent]
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  blogPostTitle = "Title";
  blogPostForm: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, private datePipe: DatePipe) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blogPostForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required]],

    })
  }

  get errorControl() {
    return this.blogPostForm.controls;
  }

}
```

The problem is I can't bind the title to the dynamic formcontrol attribute. Also the validation is not working.

I have tried several solutions and syntax like using the dataype as a FormControl. I get the following error in my console.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')
> Error: Cannot find control with name: '[object Object]'

I think the binding is working but not the validation. How can I validate the child component from the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

You need your `[formValue]` input to be `blogPostForm.get('title').value`

Comment: Hello! Thanks for you time. When I add value I get the following error: `Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute`

Comment: And when I add `generalForm.controls[formValue].errors?` I get this error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')`

Comment: Looks like you want to pass your control name for formValue input -> in this case which is 'title'. There are many ways you can pass it. Try harcoding the value for now and see if that works.